Programmatically create named functions in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script
There is a fairly new but powerful feature in Google Sheets, called named function.
Just double checking, that it is not possible to create such named function programmatically, using Google Apps Script?
P.S. I know it is possible to create a custom function in google apps script, but this is not what I am asking for.

Currently, it doesn't seem possible to interact with Named functions through Apps script or the Google sheets API.   (Though the function definitions themselves, can be retrieved(and created) by converting to (and from) xlsx, as demonstrated by Tanaike's script). This feature is already requested at the  issuetracker. To show support for this feature, add "+1"(on top right) in the link below and share the issue with users who need it:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/262981951
